# CruiseControl.NET and UI automation testing

Tags: cruisecontrol.net, ui-automation

I am using White as my framework for my UI automation testing.
Can I use CruiseControl.NET (that is running as a service), to run the tests written by White?

I have been trying for a whole day without success.
The White framework requires interactive desktop.
The error message I am getting is : "Couldn't find main window created for application"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We don't use White but TestComplete. It should be the same advice anyway: You need to run CCNET from console instead of running as a service.